# codeigniter batch update of specific form field based on its ID

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to do an `update_batch` in codeigniter in the most concise way possible. My form consists of a loop in which I generate a bunch of input fields that will affect the `val` column of my `extra_config` database:

```
<?php echo form_open('config/edit') ?>
<table>
<?php foreach ($config_by_page[$i] as $config_item): ?>
<tr class="config-row">
    <td><?php echo $config_item['description'] ; ?></td>
    <td class="edit"><input required data-id="<?php echo $config_item['id'] ?>" name="val" value="<?php echo $config_item['val'] ; ?>"></input></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
</form>
```

Right now - I have the id of the row each "val" is supposed to be tied to stored in the data attribute `data-id` because I'm not sure how to do an `update_batch()` and have the val inserted into the appropriate table row.

Here's my controller:

```
$data = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);
$this->config_model->edit_config($data);
```

and here's my model:

```
public function edit_config($data){
  $this->db->update_batch('extra_scenarios', $data,'id');
}
```

How do I most concisely include the id of the row the batch update should post to? I don't want to have to make a big data array manually because there are almost 100 different rows I need to update.

Comment: yiu are trying to update `val` field??

Comment: yes, update the val field where id column equals the id attribute from the input field (or get this input id some other way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the issue

```
name="val"
```

this should be an array

```
name="val[]"
```

Comment: Sorry - I'm confused - how will it know that the val should be tied to the appropriate id? There are multiple columns in my table and it needs to know to update the "val" field of each row where id is equal to id from the post

Comment: see above answer, do like this, `name="val[database id here]"`

Comment: If I do this without changing the model or controller somehow, I get: `One or more rows submitted for batch updating is missing the specified index.`

Comment: the $data from the post looks like this: `Array ( [val] => Array ( [3] => 37.10119357072203 [4] => -122.06634521484374 [5] => 37.51571709945411...`

Comment: I figured this out - your answer was helpful. Once you have val[] for each field, you can modify the model to create an array of arrays: containing the key and value: `foreach ($data['val'] as $i=>$val_item){
            $val_data[] = array(
            'id' => $i,
            'val' => $val_item
            );
        }` and `$this->db->update_batch('extra_config', $val_data,'id');`

Comment: Glad i could help you:)

Answer (score 1):

You can change input field name as below so you will get array of config on submit :

```
<input required name="config[<?php echo $config_item['id'];?>]" value="<?php echo $config_item['val'] ; ?>"/>
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm not sure how to modify my model to use this data though?